# How to balance data when they look like a 3-D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a numpy_array of size `(3275412, 50, 22)` which represents my data reshaped for LSTM purposes and I have got a target vector of shape `(3275412,)`.

I want to balance my data so that there is approximately the same number of data with target `0` and `1`.
The way I prepared the data makes that I can not do this balancing operation before reshaping.

Firstly, I wanted to apply `make_imbalance` function (see [this link](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.datasets.make_imbalance.html#imblearn.datasets.make_imbalance) for details) but I can't apply it on a 2-D array (got an error).

My question is : what's the most efficient way to do it for a 3D array ?

My thoughts: I thought about firstly "flatten" my 3-D array to a 2-D array by "concatenating" the second and third dimension (but don't know how so please tell me ??) then apply `make_imbalance` and then reshape the result to a 3-D array (again, don't know how to do). It seems a little bit tricky however...

So any help would be appreciated, either for an other imbalancing method or for help about reshaping 3D->2D or vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.reshape` with `-1` for unknown dimension size.

```
data2d = data3d.reshape(data3d.shape[0], -1)
```

will give you a 2d array of shape `(n_samples, n_features)` 
with the second and the third dimensions merged.

```
data2d_new, y_new = make_imbalance(data2d, y)
```

After `make_imbalance` call, you will get a 2d array with a shape `(n_samples_new, n_features)`, where the number of rows is "unknown" but you know your other two 'feature' dimensions of the original 3d array, so

```
data3d_new = data2d.reshape(-1, data3d.shape[1], data3d.shape[2])
```

will give you back the balanced 3d dataset.